Unable to create new private key to use firebase
I need to use Firestore for my new project. My account email is kapil@n29.tech. When I try to create new private key in firebase I get the error “Key creation is not allowed on this service account. Please check if service account key creation is restricted by organisation policies.“. The Firebase service account shown is
firebase-adminsdk-xjylz@yellowball-442903.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Then I am logged into google cloud console using my email kapil@n29.tech. In the IAM section my email kapil@n29.tech is listed as a principal and role is owner. firebase-adminsdk-xjylz@yellowball-442903.iam.gserviceaccount.com is also listed as another principal. After some search on web, I read that under "organisation policies" a policy called constraints/iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation should be relaxed for me to be able to create new private key. However there is no way for me to relax this policy as the manage policy is disabled.
I am stuck and need help. Strangely when I switch to organisation "n29.tech" and navigate to "organisation policies" I see error "You need additional access to the organisation:  n29.tech". I (kapil@n29.tech) am the owner so totally confused.
